# Sql Server out on parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

What does out mean on a stored procedure?

```
Create Procedure [schema].[proc_Name]
@valueone int out
As
Begin 
    Update [Table] set Value = @valueone
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing (in this particular case)

Otherwise it is an output parameter as you probably suspected. So if you change the value of @valueone inside the stored proc, that value will be returned to the caller.

Comment: Ok, so this is another way to define an output parameter.  I am used to output not out.  Are you aware of any performance impact of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

It means you can pass information "Out" of the procedure, useful for an inserted row to get the ID or something like that

this code sample should explain it.

```
Create Procedure dbo.[proc_Name]
    @valueone int out
As
Begin 

    set @valueone =  @valueone + 1 

end

GO

declare @valueone int

set @valueone =99

exec [proc_Name] @valueone OUT

select @valueone
```